# c# Convert path to a new path with \\

Tags: c#, path

Im trying to convert a path. I have this path:

```
   C:\myfolder\test.jpg
```

Im trying to convert to:

```
  C:\\myfolder\\teste.jpg
```

I cant just use "@" before the path in my application. It need to be like that, with the twice .

How can I do that?

Comment: Where are you getting that path from? The slashes may already be escaped if you read it in from somewhere.

Comment: Why do you need to escape slashes? :0

Comment: Why escape `/`? It doesn't need it.

Comment: Ohh Sorry guys.. I mean this   \

Comment: String.Replace? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I cant replace because its two slashes.

Comment: Why can't you replace? You can replace any string you want with any other string you want... Are you familiar with escaping characters in c#?

Comment: I think you need to explain what problem you're trying to solve by doing this. There's a chance you're going about it the wrong way... whatever "it" might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you want this to escape backslashes you can just use a verbatim string.

But, if you want to replace one backslash with two and see it in the actual output as two slash then you can use `string.Replace` method

```
// first way
var path = @"C:\myfolder\test.jpg".Replace("\\","\\\\");

// second way
var path = @"C:\myfolder\test.jpg".Replace(@"\",@"\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have string stored in a string,

```
     string path ="C:\myfolder\test.jpg";
     path=path.Replace("\","\\");
```